# QGIS - Unique Labels In

Tags: qgis, python

In a shape file, I have the following structure:

```
id | NM_SUBDIST
1  | x
2  | y
3  | y
4  | y
5  | z
6  | z
```

The map is plotted according to the id's, ie the id's are subdivisions represented on the map. However, I wanted the labels to be plotted according to the 'NM_SUBDIST' column, without repeating. I am using the following function in python:

```
def labels():
   v = iface.activeLayer()
   idx = fields().indexFromName('NM_SUBDIST')
   vals = v.uniqueValues(idx)
   return vals
```

This function, return the unique values of 'NM_SUBDIST'. But I can't apply this function to the map. How can I do this?

Comment: Try to dissolve your shape by NM_SUBDIST, tem label and show the dissolved one